# İn pandas. I need to search the information ı get from the user in the available data and print the other values in the row

Tags: python, pandas

```
data summery.xlsx
part number                   serial number
abcd Part number:1234 abcd    xyz

import pandas as pd
#my data
excel_file = 'summery.xlsx'
data = pd.read_excel(excel_file)

part number = input("enter part number")
```

I want to be able to get the serial number from the line by searching the part number information in the data

Answer (score 1):

My idea is,
Firstly we can read it as a dataframe and search for the particular word in the sentence in the column.

wrd = df[df['col1'].fillna(0).str.contains("abcd",na=False)]

then we can extract the corresponding values of it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can't have space in the variable name so rename it:

```py
part_number = input("enter part number")
```

Then find out the row and print the `['serial number']` column:

```py
print(data[data['part number'] == part_number]['serial number'])
```

Comment: when ı apply this it gives a key error for part number

Comment: That could mean your column name is not exactly `part number`. You need to provide the exact name.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to filter your dataframe. The most intuitive way of indexing/filtering a dataframe in pandas is using [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

The overall syntax is  `df.loc[row_indexer, col_indexer]`
Once you have the required part number, just filter your dataframe as follows:

 `df.loc["part number" == part_number, "serial number"]` 
 where  `part_number`  is the input from the user

Answer (score 0):

You can select columns from your data variable by doing the following:

```
part_number = data["number"]
```

You take the data that you read from the excel and access the information you want by putting the column name inside the brackets as a string.
Additionally, if you need specific rows you can do:

```
part_number = data["number"][1]
```

And don't use spaces in variable names. It's gonna get treated as 2 different variables.